# Cannot navigate to request page while User Profile Synchronization Is Running

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync

I'm trying to create new Synchronization connection, when I Click on create new connection button it Shows below message

[image]

For that I have done below steps

Open the Central Administration > Manage Service applications
Click to open the User Profile Service(UPS) application
Click the "Stop" link from the right-down of the page. The link is under "Profile Synchronization Settings" section.

Here Is the Screen shot of 
Manage Profile Service: User Profile Service Application

[image]

Still it shows messgae **Cannot navigate to request page while User Profile Synchronization Is Running**
Please Suggest Some Workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop and Start the `User Profile Synchronization Service` from Services on the server page!

Make sure after start service, it should not stuck on `starting`

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things to check

- restart sharepoint timer service on the server where UPA sync provisioned
- check from central admin, timer job status if upa sync job still running
- stop and start upa sync
- may be you have to clear config cache on the upa sync server